# Profiling magento (category manager) using xdebug profiler

Tags: debug, profiler, xdebug

I am looking at reported speed issue in admin category manager, where some categories can take up to 2 minutes of load time after the tree view was clicked. There are now errors anywhere, simply just (sometimes) take very long to load.

Since I had never used xdebug profiler (cachegrind) result inside PHPStorm, I figured this is a great opportunity to try that out, and see how PHPSTorm deals with the data.

However, I have run into an issue: The profiled page load never seems to end, or is just simply taking soooo long to profile, it s simply not viable to use.

I initiated the page load of a category (profiled) 12 hours ago, and it is still loading! - that is simply not practical. I can see the cachegrind file is still being written by using a `watch ls -la` on terminal

So, my question(s) are:

Has someone done this, using xdebug profiler, specifically on category admin page?
Is the issue directly related to my environment, or has someone else have this happen?

Any advise, or suggestions profiling another way? (I am aware of AOE_Profiler, and use it a lot, just wanted to try using xdebug profiler)

In case it is of importance, my xdebug ini is this:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=On
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir=/var/www/html/var/profiler
xdebug.max_nesting_level=200
xdebug.profiler_output_name="%R-%u.trace"
xdebug.profiler_append=On
```

Directly after this question, I am going to attempt profile another admin section, to see if that works faster.

PS: this is done on a core i7 CPU, with 12G memory, so should be more than enough processing power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On office machine, Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1245 v3 @ 3.40GHz, it takes 10 seconds for the same thing!

So issue is with home machine. Maybe time to upgrade hardware!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it hasn't stopped on a break point in your project in PHPStorm ? Check the debug tab.

Comment: Good suggestion, and I did check that. debugging was disabled.